# Assign object instance to static variable

Tags: java, swing, static, jtable

following issue. I have a static method with static members and one should contain a JTable instance of my own table class:

> `public class MyTable extends JTable`

but this

> `private static MyTable configTable = new MyTable();`

will lead to `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

But why?
If I would write

> `private static JTable configTable = new JTable();`

it would compile without any problems. Where's the difference?
Anyway to achieve it anyway except changing all my Classes to non-static or switching MyTable to a static method :(?

Cheers

Comment: your class `MyTable` is an inner class? Try posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: this is not a coding problem, this is a general question about how java handles static members. There is nothing to "execute" and no point in presenting a SSCCE. And there is no reason to downvote here. I googled and no one ever said something about inner classes. So thanks anyway -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible explanation is that you have declared `MyTable` as an "inner class": a class that belongs to an instance of the enclosing class. In a static context no such instance exists, and that's why the compiler complains. To fix this, declare the class as `static`:

```
public static class MyTable extends JTable {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `MyTable` class is a non-static inner class of that class where you trying to declare that static variable. 
Generally, to construct an instance of a non-static inner class you must provide the instance of outer class to which it will be bound. Just like :

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

If you instantiate the `Inner` for current (`this`) object - you write

`Inner inner = this.new Inner();`

But java syntax lets you not to use `this` keyword explicitly in such case, so you can just  write

`Inner inner = new Inner();`

Your concrete problem is occurs because you trying to use the dynamic reference (`this`) in a static context. So if you dont need the `Inner` to be dynamically referenced with `Outer` - just add the `static` modifier for `Inner` class declaration.